# plotting array of -> expressions

Tags: plotting, functions, list-manipulation

I want to plot the following array as functions $a(w)$

```
{{a -> 0}, {a -> 0}, {a -> 
   0}, {a -> -1.50919*10^33 Sqrt[-3.62327*10^-24 + 2.29858*10^-54 w - 
     4.39048*10^-67 w^2]}, {a -> 
   1.50919*10^33 Sqrt[-3.62327*10^-24 + 2.29858*10^-54 w - 
     4.39048*10^-67 w^2]}, {a -> -(1/2) Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 - 
     5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 1.56362*10^13 w - 
     4 w^2]}, {a -> 
   1/2 Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 - 
     5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 1.56362*10^13 w - 
     4 w^2]}, {a -> -(1/2) Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 + 
     5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 1.56362*10^13 w - 
     4 w^2]}, {a -> 
   1/2 Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 + 
     5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 1.56362*10^13 w - 
     4 w^2]}}
```

I'm pretty new to Mathematic. How can I do this ?

Comment: if the above is say `lis` then you can do `Plot[a /. lis, {w, 0, .1}]` to plot them. But these generate complex values for `w`. Hence you can replace the above with `Plot[Abs[a /. lis], {w, 0, .1}]`

Comment: okay thanks that works :) and how can I label them ? I would like to know which graph corresponds to which expression in the array

Comment: usually `PlotLegends` should just do it. Does not here. Needs more investigation. maybe someone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @Nasser's comment

```
list = {{a -> 0}, {a -> 0}, {a -> 
     0}, {a -> -1.50919*10^33 Sqrt[-3.62327*10^-24 + 
        2.29858*10^-54 w - 4.39048*10^-67 w^2]}, {a -> 
     1.50919*10^33 Sqrt[-3.62327*10^-24 + 2.29858*10^-54 w - 
        4.39048*10^-67 w^2]}, {a -> -(1/2) Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 - 
        5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 
        1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}, {a -> 
     1/2 Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 - 
        5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 
        1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}, {a -> -(1/2) Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 + 
        5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 
        1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}, {a -> 
     1/2 Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 + 
        5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] + 
        1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}};

Plot[Evaluate@Abs[a /. list], {w, 0, .1},
 PlotLabels -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the accept. The plot becomes interesting only for large values of `w`, try `{w, 1, 3*10^21}`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 9x1 matrix.
Firstly you can manipulate the cells by deleting "a->" and have a new matrix.
And you have a new matrix with cells of w dependant functions.You can define this matrix as:

a = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {-1.50919*10^33 Sqrt[-3.62327*10^-24 +
2.29858*10^-54 w -
4.39048*10^-67 w^2]}, {1.50919*10^33 Sqrt[-3.62327*10^-24 +
2.29858*10^-54 w -
4.39048*10^-67 w^2]}, {-(1/2) Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 -
5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] +
1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}, {1/
2 Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 -
5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] +
1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}, {-(1/2) Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 +
5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] +
1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}, {1/
2 Sqrt[-8.25255*10^42 +
5.74545*10^21 Sqrt[(3.90906*10^12 - 2 w)^2] +
1.56362*10^13 w - 4 w^2]}};

First 3 functions are zero, no plot necessary.
So you need to plot 6 functions.
You can see each function as:

a[[4,1]]

a[[5,1]]

a[[6,1]]

a[[7,1]]

a[[8,1]]

a[[9,1]]

and your function is complex, you can change w with x+yi as:

a[[4,1]]/.w->x+i y

a[[5,1]]/.w->x+i y

a[[6,1]]/.w->x+i y

a[[7,1]]/.w->x+i y

a[[8,1]]/.w->x+i y

a[[9,1]]/.w->x+i y

Then,in order to plot for 4. cell function,
you can define a function as:

f[x_, y_] := -1.50919`*^33 Sqrt[-3.623270000000001`*^-24 +
2.2985799999999997`*^-54 (x + I y) - 4.39048`*^-67 (x + I y)^2]

The function above is a result of:

a[[4,1]]/.w->x+i y

and plot it for real and imaginary parts:

ContourPlot[Re@f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10]

ContourPlot[Im@f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10]

You can change axis range and plot point numbers.